# Exchange Server IIS Setup on DC

Tags: iis, outlook-web-app

I have one server that I have setup with a Domain Controller (running 2012) and Exchange 2013.

I can get email in and out fine, but I'm having trouble getting IIS to show me the OWA page. At the moment I've setup all the MX and A records correctly, but when I go to "mail.mydomain.com" it brings up the default IIS page.

How do I configure IIS to point to OWA please?

Comment: Can you add some details about your IIS setup? Is there one website, or more than one? Have you done anything with bindings / host headers? Did you setup OWA / Exchange following any particular guide, or did anything go wrong during it, etc.

Comment: There is only the default website in IIS. As I said, all I've done is setup a new Domain Controller and installed Exchange 2013 on it. I can't find the guide I followed exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the default web site. OWA is not the default web site. You need to add `/exchange` to the URL in your browser.

`https://mail.mydomain.com/exchange`

Comment: https://mail.mydomain.com/owa worked, "exchange" didn't. Guess it's an Exchange 2013 thing.
How do I change in IIS so that the default points to the OWA page?

Comment: This started me on the right path, thank you. I found this link that has a great step through: http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-url-redirection-in-exchange-2013/